# Is possible to avoid declaring StaticDatabaseConfig annotation in every class using tsql in Slick 3.x?

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

If I want to use compiled time queries in Slick 3.x, I need to declare a StaticDatabaseConfig annotation in every class using tsql.

Is there any way to avoid this and set a global config?

```
@StaticDatabaseConfig("file:src/main/resources/application.conf#tsql")
object PersistenceService {
  val database = Database.forConfig("database")
  database.run( tsql"SELECT NOW()" )
}
```